# S3 versioning with django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

I use **[django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages)** in my app, and I want to use [**S3 versioning**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) just out of the box. I mean, **I want to store and retrieve different versions of the same file** without implementing any additional mechanism.

By reading the docs, I understand that:

- Retrieving an object is as easy as [adding a version=XX parameter to the GET request.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html)
- Uploading an object is handled by S3 itself. You just need to [configure versioning in your bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#how-to-enable-disable-versioning-intro)

But, going to the code. If I have this:

```
from django.db import models

from django_s3_storage.storage import S3Storage

storage = S3Storage(aws_s3_bucket_name='test_bucket')

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    s3_file = models.FileField(storage=storage)
```

How can I get one specific version of a Document? Something like:

```
doc = Document.objects.get(pk=XX)
doc.s3_file.read(version=XXXXXXXXXX) # Something like this?
```

I've been reading the official documentation, but can't find how to:

- **Get available versions of an object**
- **Retrieve one specific version**

**EDIT**: Reading the source code, I understand I could use [*parameters* in url() call](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto3.py#L609), but not sure about what parameter (version?) and how to get the existent version of an object.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) I'd expect the parameter to be `version-id`. That's not the version number, but an id, which can be fetched using [`list-object-versions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html), you can do that using the boto3 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the comment of @dirkgroten was pretty accurate. So:

- [get-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) using version-id to get a specific version of an object
- [list-object-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) to get all available versions of an object